# How can I compile Numpy on Mac despite clang error?

Tags: macos, numpy, clang

I am trying to follow the installation instructions here: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/building.html#building-from-source

I ran `pip install .` from inside a virtual environment.

Unfortunately, it errors.   Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/SnVqSau8

A key part that looks important is:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
      clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
      Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
```

and

```
  error: Command "/usr/bin/clang++ ..." failed with exit status 254
```

The output also suggests that I include the following files in any bug reports:
`/var/folders/kv/m2g0jrv52t5651m602p2t_r80000gn/T/simd_qsort_16bit-8cb705.sh`: https://pastebin.com/5sMRUd5j
`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash`:
https://pastebin.com/D8H04f1A
It also suggests sharing a ~285,000 line long `.cpp` file corresponding to the above `.sh` file, but I can't figure out how to copy paste that into pastebin without crashing my computer.

Do you have any thoughts of things I could try in order to build this Numpy installation?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/23730

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/23711#issuecomment-1535242735